# Ansible - How to print skipped tasks' names when --check?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I run playbook with `--check` option I see  names only for `ok` or `changed` tasks.

```yaml
TASK [playbook : taskN] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [host00.domain]

TASK [playbook : taskN+1] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [host00.domain]

TASK [playbook : taskN+2] ************************************************************************************************
changed: [host00.domain] => (item=item_stuff)

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************
host00.domain         : ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I see `skipped=2`, but which exactly tasks were skipped ? `-vvv` doesn't helped.

Example of skipped task:

**`tasks/main.yml`**

```yaml
- import_tasks: taskF.yml
  when: "'host_group' in group_names"
```

**`tasks/taskF.yml`**

```yaml
- name: test network
  shell: echo AAA
  tags: full, test
```

Comment: try posting your playbook content as well.

Comment: I've updated post, but I don't know how playbook may help you, I want to print skipped tasks in all possible cases.

Comment: increasing verbosity should help. The output you posted tells the verbosity was set to 0. It normally shows the skipped tasks. I have outputs available with me of my jobs.

Comment: -vvv doesn't help -  I wrote this in first edition. Verbosity affects only details of already  printed tasks (ok, changed). Skipped tasks always show as summary.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`default` callback – default Ansible screen output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html) the [Parameter: `display_skipped_hosts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html#parameter-display_skipped_hosts) with `ansible.cfg` should do it.

```ini
[defaults]
display_skipped_hosts   = yes
```

A minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - import_tasks: taskF.yml
    when: true
```

```yaml
- name: Test network
  shell: echo $(hostname)
  tags: full, test
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook main.yml --check
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *********

TASK [Test network] ******
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Whereby configured to

```ini
[defaults]
display_skipped_hosts   = no
```

it would result into

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *********

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```